# choose multiple files from client(jquery, ajax) and send to server(express)

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, multer

When a client clicks on the upload file, I want to take multiple files and upload to server on upload button click. Here I am using an express server with multer.
I tried with single file choose & upload, it works fine. But I am unable to find out for multiple file uploads.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Upload File</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
      <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="./main/script/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// main.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#uploadForm").submit(function() {
    var data = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/upload',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      data: data,
      success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error: In sending the request!');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

```js
// uploadfile.js
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require('fs');
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");

//set Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/storage/'),
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000 //give no. of bytes
  },
  // fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
  //     checkFileType(file, cb);
  // }
}).single('uploadFile');

// function checkFileType(file, cb){
//     console.log(file);
//     // // Allowed extensions
//     // const filetypes = /xlsx|xlx|csv/;
//     // //check ext
//     // var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase());
//     // var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
//     // if(extname  mimetype){
//     //     return cb(null, true);
//     // }else{
//     //     return cb('Error: Invalid file types!');
//     // }
// }

function uploadFile(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      //Send error msg
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      //send correct msg
      //res.send()
      res.send('Successful');
      console.log('file uploaded succcessfully');
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  uploadFile
}
```

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan  Thanks. Will update soon

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I tried to change it. But Sof doesnt allowing me to submit post telling that you have huge code. So I dont have a choice. Please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: I edited it for you

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your multer function and change to `array` from `single`

```
var upload = multer({ 
    storage : storage 
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000 //give no. of bytes
    },
}).array('uploadFile');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still face problem at jquery side. Can you help with that please.

Comment: What's the issue on the jQuery side? Your code is fine, you just need to add more file inputs, or set the `multiple` attribute on the single one you have

Comment: I agree with you Rory. But how can I send the data using formData for all files choosen using multiple attribute?